# Ensuring consistency with relational database without foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have seen examples like [discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse) where tables in relational database don't have foreign keys. While the other tenants of RDB are still used like CONSTRAINTS, INDEXES , FULLTEXTSEARCH etc.. but as per Rails Active record guidelines , foreign keys are dropped.

> https://meta.discourse.org/t/foreign-key-constraints-in-db/2642

Do we need to periodically check for consistency in such applications ? And in that case should it be done for each request -response that there is no invalid foreign key and correct it at same time in application layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so the first thing to understand is why we generally put such constraints in the database.  The second point will be why some people don't like this.  The third will be what the ramifications of not doing so are.

**Why we put RI checks in the database**

A relational database is basically a big math engine performing set (well, actually bag, due to concessions with real-world data integrity problems) operations on large sets of data.  As the sets grow, the ability to verify integrity of the data reduces until at some point one has trouble verifying the entire validity of the data according to the set model one follows.  I have worked with PostgreSQL databases where constraints were not possible, so that in some areas we had to accept that there would be referential integrity violations.

The problem of managing referential integrity where one software project owns the database can be formidable, but they can become far worse when many different programs can read or write the same data.  This gets worse because normalization and encapsulation concerns increase with the number of pathways for reading (and worse, writing) the data.

Ensuring that one can make sure that referential integrity is not violated on each write is thus an important tool in data management.

**Why some people avoid RI checks in the database**

Referential integrity constraints however are not free.  There are two important drawbacks to using them that sometimes cause developers to decide not to.

1. Referential integrity checks are not free.  They do impact database performance, and often the database is understood to be the least scalable part of a system, and
2. They divide logic, placing it in different locations and segregating data model logic from application logic.  While this separation of concerns is usually desirable, where a single application owns a database, it is sometimes (but not always!) considered to be a less desirable tradeoff.

It is worth noting further that Rails guidelines don't offer solid guidance on this tradeoff.  Like many ORMs, Active Record offers tools for addressing this in the application, I found plenty of examples of people using foreign keys in the database, and nobody saying "don't use them."

**Concerns from avoiding RI checks in the database**

The concerns and further mitigating measures of course depend on the importanc and further use of data.  A lower-impact data set which is just the private data store of an application (the normal rails way) doesn't have the same implications as a higher-impact data store used that is intended to be used for decision support later.  So repeated read-use is am important question in deciding whether you need to periodically re-scan.

The second concern are alternate sources of writes.  In general in this model the most important concern is to prevent alternate sources of writes, outside of uses of these specific ActiveRecord-using classes.

So in answer to your question, you  may or may not need to.  But you should probably do a risk assessment and decide what to do.  Such a risk assessment will guide this decision not only at the moment but also in the future.

**As a side note**

You can use foreign keys to insist on consistency while using the hooks and so forth to ensure that the logic is properly handled in the ActiveRecord component.  I.e. instead of using `ON DELETE CASCADE` have that handled by a hook.